# Setting DayNight theme using AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode() not working for FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, theme-daynight

I'm a bit puzzled. I'm using a DayNight theme in my app (using `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()`), but can't get it to work in my `MainActivity`. 
The `MainActivity` (which extends `FragmentActivity`) looks like it's never set to dark theme - **it always remains in light theme**.

I tried setting the theme directly in my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // create main activity.
}
```

But this is not working.

I have set all of the colors in my layout files properly using ?attr/colorReference. Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

**EDIT:**
My styles.xml is as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!--Default typeface and colors:-->
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorAccentDarker">@color/colorAccentDarker</item>
    <item name="colorAccentDarker_80percent">@color/colorAccentDarker_80percent</item>

    <!--Show people's own wallpaper background-->
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Could you show us your `style.xml` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `MainActivity` (which extends `FragmentActivity`)

`FragmentActivity` has no idea of AppCompat. `AppCompatDelegate` is only used by `AppCompatActivity` or you have to [wire it manually](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate) to your other activities.

You can extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: This works for me but introduced these side effects: an ugly title popping up and the transparent background of buttons no longer being transparent

Comment: @riezebosch 1. I suspect you set android:background in themes, don't do that, it's a widget/style attribute. You may want to google "themes vs styles android" and read up on the differences. 2. AppCompat button style is "buttonStyle" as opposed to plain Android's "android:buttonStyle". Many other widgets follow suit. Update your theme accordingly and it should work again.

Comment: please help with this device specific issue, if you have any idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71333304/android-dark-light-mode-not-working-in-android